# Accord de l'adjectif "spécialisé"

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Avec ma compagne nous avons une question sur l'accord de l'adjectif "spécialisé" dans la phrase:

> Ingénieur agronome spécialisé dans la gestion des ressources et de l'environnement, je vous adresse ma candidature [...]

Cette phrase est extraite de la lettre de motivation de ma compagne. Nous avons un doute sur l'accord de `spécialisé`: doit-il y avoir `é` ou `ée` à la fin?

Nous pensons que c'est possible avec les deux accords, selon si l'on s'accorde avec Ingénieur (masculin) ou la personne qui a écrit la lettre (ma compagne, féminin).

Comment: Vu la tendance actuelle, certain(e) dirait « Ingénieur**e** agronome spécialisé**e** », ce que, par ailleurs, je n'approuve pas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En respectant les règles traditionnelles, une virgule suffisait à rendre incontestable le féminin :

> Ingénieur agronome, spécialisée dans la gestion des ressources et de l'environnement, je vous adresse ma candidature [...]

mais de nos jours, on peut facilement résoudre le problème en mettant *ingénieur* [au féminin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ing%C3%A9nieure) :

> Ingénieure agronome spécialisée dans la gestion des ressources et de l'environnement, je vous adresse ma candidature [...]

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que c'est possible mais pas sans un petit changement qui permettrait de préserver une claire identité des catégories grammaticales (ingénieur en tant que fonction, sujet « je »). Cette tournure d'apposition est équivalente à des forme plus explicites (et/ou lourdes) telles que « Je suis ingénieur agronome et je suis spécialisée …, Je suis ingénieur agronome, je suis spécialisée …, et je vous …). En préservant la virgule on obtient quelque chose qui n'est pas trop alourdi de précisions et répétitions ;  d'une apposition on en fait deux reliée par une virgule.

- Ingénieur agronome, spécialisée dans la gestion des ressources et de l'environnement, je vous adresse ma candidature [...]

Mais bien sûr, on est confronté dans cette question, comme souvent, à un problème d'établissement de conventions et les conventions ne sont que des conventions. Donc, pourquoi ne pas donner à « Ingénieur agronome spécialisée dans …» pleine légitimité selon un principe nouveau ? Je ne sais pas, je ne peux avoir qu'une toute petite responsabilité dans la décision, et cela pas avant une considération compréhensive des implications (beaucoup d'étude, je crois).